# Why Nawab Shirajuddawla lost in the battle of Palashy (Plassey)?

Tags: political-history, indian

I know that Nawab had 50000 soldier but on the other side English soldier was 3000 and I also know that because Mir Zafar and some other guys Nawab lost the battle.

My question is only for Mir Zafar and the betrayer of Nawab  did Nawab lost the battle inspite of having 50000 soldier ? Actually my book always mention that only for some specific person Nawab lost the battle is it true ?

Comment: I would say that the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Plassey) article offers a reasonable explanation of what happened - essentially Mir Zafar withheld his forces (which made up the bulk of the Mughal army) in return for being made the next Nawab. So the actual battle itself was much more evenly balanced that it would appear on paper.